# How to generate unhandled MFC exception?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

I want to test "ProcessWndProcException" function which should catch unhandled MFC exceptions. So I need a simple example, which will generate an unhandled MFC exception. Googling did not help much, so maybe anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend searching StackOverflow for why MFC exceptions are happening.  Use the code in question.  :)

Comment: In the question, there is pointed ProcessWndProcException(CException* e, const MSG* pMsg) function, which is actually the code!

Comment: You cannot generate an *"unhandled exception"*. You need to raise an exception and do it in code that doesn't have any exception frames installed other than the top-level unhandled exception filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just throw a `CException` and not catch it anywhere.

[Exception Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e583tzca(v=vs.110).aspx) has information about various functions provided by MFC to throw exceptions.

```
// Throw a CMemoryException
AfxThrowMemoryException();
```

Bonus Info: [Exceptions: Throwing Exceptions from Your Own Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2sw1zhe.aspx)

Comment: With MFC you shouldn't throw the `CException` object itself, you should throw a *pointer* to it.